# dynamic fields class change per list element and Js to recognize part of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

class in the list element change per box and are dynamic fields with width and length being the difference between the two. How to run my JS so that only the first part of the class is recognized without the number so js variable selectors should be '.attribute__swatch--width-' and '.attribute__swatch--length-'. please see my code below:

```js
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".attribute__swatch--width-"),
    letters = document.querySelectorAll(".attribute__swatch--length-"),
    ua = navigator.userAgent,
    event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

numbers.forEach(function(box, index) {
  $(box).on(event, function() {
    letters.forEach(function(box) {
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];
    if (index > 2) {
      info.style.left = 11 + ((index - 3) * 45) + 'px';
    } else {
      info.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    }
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });
  $(document).on("click", '.clicked', function() {
    $('.clicked').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:15px auto;padding:0;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:15px auto;padding:0;}
.showBorder { outline: 1px dashed #233354; outline-offset:1px;}
.box-tip {
  display:inline;
  margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
  padding-left:10px;
 }

.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 90%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.numberCircle span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

li.selected {color:#fff;background-color:#000;}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .box-tip span {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .box-tip span.numberCircle {
    position: fixed;
    left: 236px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Test some logic one width</span>

<ul class="list-box">
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-14.5">1</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-15">2</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-15.5">3</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-16">4</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-16.5">5</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-17">6</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-17.5">7</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--width-18">8</li>
</ul>
<div>
<span>Test some logic two length</span>
</div>
<div class="box-tip">
  <span>Regular length for your collar size</span>
  <span class="numberCircle">?</span>
</div>
<ul class="box-sleeve">
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-32">a</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-34">b</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-36">c</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-38">d</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-40">e</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-42">f</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-44">g</li>
  <li class="attribute__swatch--length-46">h</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), specifically starts with (`^=`) to match:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('[class^="attribute__swatch--width-"]');
 document.querySelectorAll('[class^="attribute__swatch--length-"]')
```

Comment: great answer dude.

Comment: Any idea how I can attach .box-tip to only apply and display if attribute__swatch--length- not attribute__swatch--width-

Comment: @Olivbelle glad it was helpful! I'm not sure I understand your follow up question. You can use `.box-tip[class^="attribute__swatch--length"]` if that's what you mean